# Create Active Directory Username

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We use a username format of "First Initial of Firstname First Initial of Middle and First Initial of Last Name".

I need a way to change the middle initial if the username already exists in AD. It should cycle through the letters of the alphabet until it finds an available match.

Below is what I have right now in PowerShell and it's able to set the username correctly and check if it exists in Active Directory. However, I can't figure out how to change the middle initial.
Any suggestions?

I've updated my code to the below but I don't know how to get it to check AD again with the new username.

```
$randomObject = New-Object System.Random
$randomChar = [char]$randomObject.next(97, 122)

$FirstName  = ’rirstName’
$MiddleName = 'aiddleName'
$LastName   = ’gastName’

$Username = $Firstname.Substring(0, 1) + $Middlename.Substring(0, 1) +
            $Lastname.Substring(0, 1)

$User = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $Username}
if ($User -eq $null) {
    'not found'
} elseif ($User -eq $Username) {
    $MiddleName = $randomChar
    $Username   = $Firstname.Substring(0, 1) + $Middlename +
                  $Lastname.Substring(0, 1)
} else {
    $randomObject = New-Object System.Random
    $randomChar = [char]$randomObject.next(97, 122)
    $MiddleName = $randomChar
    $Username   = $Firstname.Substring(0, 1) + $Middlename +
                  $Lastname.Substring(0, 1)
}
$Username
Powershell
$FirstName  = ’FirstName’
$MiddleName = 'MiddleName'
$LastName   = ’LastName’

$Username = $Firstname.Substring(0, 1) + $Middlename.Substring(0, 1) +
            $Lastname.Substring(0, 1)

$User = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $Username}
if ($User -eq $null) {
    "User does not exist in AD"
} else {
    "User found in AD"
}
$Username
```

Comment: What's a "middle name"? Don't build logic that assumes stuff like that. That's as nonsensical as assuming that every place in the world would have a "ZIP code".

Comment: You need to loop until the account name is not found, then create the new account. Also, I would recommend avoiding typographic quotes in code.

Comment: first check your AD services by change manually than try above code.